# Best way of accessing appsetting values in services

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings

In my solution (.NET Core 2.0) I have an WebApi project and a class library Services project. I want to access values in the appsettings.json file of my WebApi project in one of my services. For example, the ones in this section.

```
"ThirdPartyApi":
{
    "ApiUrl": "xxx",
    "ApiVersion": "xxx",
    "ApiNamespace": "xxx",
    "ApiKey": "xxx",
    "Client": "xxx",
    "ClientVersion": "xxx"
}
```

From what I've seen I can do this in 2 ways:

1. Inject IConfiguration _config in my service and access the values like so:

   ```
   _config["ThirdPartyApi:ApiUrl"]
   ```
2. Create a ThirdPartyApiSettings class with properties mapping to the settings section like so:

   ```
   services.Configure<ThirdPartyApiSettings(Configuration.GetSection("ThirdPartyApi"));
   ```

   and inject `IOptions<ThirdPartyApiSettings> _apiSettings` in my service class and access the settings via the class properties as so:

   ```
   _apiSettings.ApiUrl
   ```

So, is there a preferred way between the two? Or specific use cases when one should pick one of these methods over the other?

Comment: There's actually a third option: ThirdPartyAPiSettings class with properties and inject _that settings_ class into the Services component that requires it; do not inject `IOptions<T>`. It has no function.

Comment: @Steven I was only able to do it like this: `private readonly ThirdPartyApiSettings _apiSettings; public MyService(IOptions<ThirdPartyApiSettings> apiSettings) { _apiSettings = apiSettings.Value; }`  Should this be possible: `public MyService(ThirdPartyApiSettings apiSettings) { _apiSettings = apiSettings; }` ? If so, I suspect I'm missing some configuration in Startup.cs, since I wasn't able to get it to work

Comment: You don't need any setup. Just load the `ThirdPartyApiSettings` at startup and register it as Singleton into the container. Much easier than working with Options.

Answer (score 2):

Injecting `IConfiguration` is an anti-pattern. You should create a strongly-typed class and inject that instead. As @Steven noted in the comments, `IOptions<T>` is kind of superfluous, but there is value in injecting `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`, as that will respond to config reloads. You can also get the best of both worlds and register your strongly-typed class instance as a function of `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`, so that you can inject just something like `ThirdPartyApi`, but still get config updates:

```
services.Configure<ThirdPartyApi>(Configuration.GetSection("ThirdPartyApi"));
services.AddTransient(p => p.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<ThirdPartyApi>>().Value);
```

Just be aware that with that approach the settings will be scoped to the object they're injected into. For example, if you inject into a singleton, they'll effectively never be reloaded because the update would only happen during injection. If you want to ensure you're using the most up to date config at all times, you should inject `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` directly and access the `Value` attribute each time to get at the config values.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'Injecting IConfiguration is an anti-pattern'?

Comment: "An anti-pattern is a common response to a recurring problem that is usually ineffective and risks being highly counterproductive." https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern

Comment: I suspected that there are risks associated with this. I wanted to know more specifically what those problems could be. And why/how it is ineffective. The only thing that comes to mind is that by injecting IConfiguration I am giving my service access to more data than it needs to know about.

Comment: "If you want to ensure you're using the most up to date config at all times, you should inject IOptionsSnapshot<T>directly". Instead, just make the registration Scoped; that prevents the need of letting application code depend on IOptionsSnapshot.

Comment: Yes and no. Scoped will actually prevent you from injecting into a singleton, so it has the side effect of effectively always reloading, since settings don't typically change within the context of a request. However, if you need to inject into a singleton, you must use `IOptionsSnapshot` always if you want to get the latest config. Scoped doesn't technically solve anything here.